# Origin of merry 'little' christmas

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence, christmas

Somewhere else on this site I read about the history of the sentence Merry Christmas. Frequently I encounter the sentence 'Merry little Christmas' for example in songs. I wonder what is the meaning of 'little' in this particular case?

Comment: The only place I ever heard it is in 1944's *Meet Me In St. Louis* as [a song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CreWsnhQwzY) sung by Judy Garland. I always assumed "little" was inserted so that the lyrics would scan with the melody.

Comment: I cannot find the definition in dictionaries, but one use of "little" is to indicate an air of preciousness. "Having ourselves a little party, are we?" "What exactly are you and your little friend up to?" I think these make the use in "merry, little Christmas" coherent. As @Robusto mentions, this phrasing is used quite famously in a song, though I disagree that it is likely that the phrasing is significantly compromised. The meter of the song allows many options to scan well: "very merry Christmas", "merry, merry Christmas", etc. I think the choice of "little" was truly desired.

Comment: 'Have yourself a merry little Christmas' is emphasising the cosy, fireside, tranquil, _lots of turkey and port for ... just me and my immediate family_ image – all is calm, all is (reasonably) bright – that's by no means a wrong desire but is wrong if it sums up our entire life. Imagine – a room at the inn, or we're not playing. No smelly, lowing / bleating / braying animals. No uncouth yokels or other invited guests: no over-dressed angels to embarrass us. And little children must be seen and not heard (and certainly not of questionable parentage)./ Then there's 'Do They Know It's Christmas?'

Comment: The word may signal a softening of the word _merry_ as perhaps diminishing a holy day.